XML File as Options settings file, one file different apps how to do
I have 2 independent DLLs that I'll include as part of a solution. Each one can be used without the other and I'm now building #3.
The challenge I have is the each has a global configuration and each has a workstation(PC) configuration file.
Now the Station configuration is best left as its own file but the global configuration file well that's my new issue.
In each DLL(Module) I setup a logging feature.  The setting for this is in the global Config file. In addition each DLL has its own additional settings.
First DLL config
<GlobalConfigData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <LogFilesUNC>Logs</LogFilesUNC>
  <AllowDBMaintenance></AllowDBMaintenance>
  <DBKeepDays></DBKeepDays>
  <ReportsUNC></ReportsUNC>
</GlobalConfigData>

Second DLL Config File:
<GlobalConfigData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <LogFilesUNC>Logs</LogFilesUNC>
  <DBServerURI></DBServerURI>
  <DBServerPort></DBServerPort>
</GlobalConfigData>

As you can see the LogFilesUNC is in both files.  What I want is to read and process a single config file such as:
<GlobalConfigData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <LogFilesUNC>Logs</LogFilesUNC>
</GlobalConfigData>

<DLL1ConfigData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <AllowDBMaintenance></AllowDBMaintenance>
  <DBKeepDays></DBKeepDays>
  <ReportsUNC></ReportsUNC>
</DLL1ConfigData>

<DLL2ConfigData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <DBServerURI></DBServerURI>
  <DBServerPort></DBServerPort>
</DLL2ConfigData>

I want to keep thing such that DLL1 does not need to know about DLL2 in my code.
Here is how I read the files now:
//First define the file structure:
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ReportMgr2022.Models
{
  [Serializable(), XmlRoot()]
  public class GlobalConfigData
  {
    public string LogFileUNC { get; set; } = @"Logs";
    public bool AllowDBMaintenance { get; set; } = false;
    public int DBKeepDays { get; set; } = 90;
  }
}

And the code that processes the file:
namespace ReportMgr2022
{
  internal class ConfigOptionsv2
  {
    private readonly string _CfgFQN;
    public string Message { get; private set; }

    public ConfigOptionsv2(string configFileFQN)
    {
      _CfgFQN = configFileFQN;
    }

    public bool ValidateConfigFile()
    {
      GlobalConfigData oOptions = null;
      Message = string.Empty;
      try
      {
        oOptions = LoadFromXmlFormat();
      }
      catch (Exception) { } //Error is ignorable

      if (oOptions == null)
      {
        oOptions = new GlobalConfigData();
        SaveAsXmlFormat(oOptions);
      }

      return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Message);
    }

    public bool SaveAsXmlFormat(GlobalConfigData oOptions)
    {
      XmlSerializer xmlformat = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GlobalConfigData));

      try
      {
        using (Stream fstream = new FileStream(_CfgFQN, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
          xmlformat.Serialize(fstream, oOptions);
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Message = ParseException(ex);
        return false;
      }

      return true;
    }

    public GlobalConfigData LoadFromXmlFormat()
    {
      XmlSerializer xmlformat = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GlobalConfigData));
      GlobalConfigData oOptionsFromDisk = null;

      try
      {
        using (Stream fstream = File.OpenRead(_CfgFQN))
        {
          oOptionsFromDisk = (GlobalConfigData) xmlformat.Deserialize(fstream);
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        throw new GlobalConfigException("ConfigOptionsv2.LoadFromXmlFormat", ParseException(ex), ex);
      }
      return oOptionsFromDisk;
    }

  }

  [Serializable]
  internal class GlobalConfigException : Exception
  {

    public GlobalConfigException() { }

    public GlobalConfigException(string message) : base(message) { }

    public GlobalConfigException(string source, string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner) { Source = source; }

    public GlobalConfigException(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException) { }

    protected GlobalConfigException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) { }
  }

}

I know the load and save will need change but the issue I have seems to be when DLL1 updates the DLL2 data is wiped out.  Based on the code that makes sense.  Is ther a way to do this?
My thought is that I would need to read in the entire file any time I save and then modify the individual elements for the DLL and then write the entire file back out.
Or should I create a "Global config" for just the log file and keep everything else in its own file?
